# is this correct this intead of delete trigger? and other questions about tirggers

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to to delete the children of a table when I delete the parent. The common Order/details example.

I use this instead trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_OderDelete
   ON  Oders
   INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    Delete from Details where IDOrder IN(select deleted.IDOrder from deleted)
    Delete from Orders where IDOrder IN(select deleted.IDOrder from deleted)
END
GO
```

First, I try with only the fist delete statement, but only delete de details, not the orders, so I added the second delete to delete the order too.

My doubt is if this is correct or not. I mean that if the trigger is executed when I delete an order, why have I to added the delete statement in the trigger to delete the order that execute the trigger?

I also would like to know this:

1.- is a transaction? I mean that if I delete the details and for some reason the order can't be deleted, finally the details are not deleted?

2.- This transaction avoid to added new details when I delete the ordener? Imagine that I want to delete an order, in the trigger is executed the  first delete, the details, but before is executed the second delete, the order, other user try to added a new detail. This detail is added or not because the order is blocked in a transaction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why have I to added the delete statement in the trigger to delete the order that execute the trigger?

Because it's an `INSTEAD OF` trigger - you've told SQL Server that you'll take responsibility for performing the delete.

> is a transaction? I mean that if I delete the details and for some reason the order can't be deleted, finally the details are not deleted?

The outer `DELETE` that caused this trigger to fire will either already be in a transaction or will have caused one to start. If an error occurs that causes your trigger to abort between the two deletes, **and** the caller has a proper strategy for dealing with errors (e.g. [`XACT_ABORT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188792%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is `ON`; or they're using `TRY`/`CATCH` or checking `@@ERROR` and calling `ROLLBACK`) then your first delete will be rolled back when the transaction rolls back.

If, OTOH, they're ignoring errors and committing transactions anyway, then you could end up with the `Details` rows still having been deleted.

> This transaction avoid to added new details when I delete the ordener? Imagine that I want to delete an order, in the trigger is executed the first delete, the details, but before is executed the second delete, the order, other user try to added a new detail. This detail is added or not because the order is blocked in a transaction?

The `DELETE` against `Details` will have taken an Exclusive lock on that table. Nobody is going to be able to execute an `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` against that table until the transaction commits.